# How to cast the shadow of the texture's alpha channel and not the actual geometry of the plane?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, shadows

So i have a simple bush scene in the blender render engine with a basic lamp and ground plane and i have also switched to material shading mode.

## The Bushes

[image]

The bushes are basically alpha planes with a leaf texture on it, i duplicated and bunched them up together. The leaf textures was imported into blender using the "Import images as planes" addon so the alpha transparency showed up in the viewport.

## The Shadows[image]

As you can see the shadows that are being casted on the groundplane are of the actual geometry and there is no affect of the transparency in it.

## The Lamp settings

[image]

Here are the lamp settings.

## The Material settings of the bush

[image]

## The Question

The shadows that are being casted on the groundplane are of the actual geometry and not of the alpha, how do i make it cast the shadow of the alpha and not the actual geometry of the alpha planes ?

## Edit: My main goal is to produce the shadows in the material view mode and not the rendered view mode because i have to switch to blender game engine later.

Comment: What do your material nodes look like or can you post an image?

Comment: Lovely plants. That shadow gives them addition effect btw, like freestyle. Screenshot of the material settings related to alpha would be nice

Comment: I have edited the question with the material of the bush

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender internal can be a bit confusing in that regard. The objects casting the shadows do not determine how those shadows are received in other objects. The receiving objects determine the quality of the shadow.

By default the receiving objects show the shadow of the pane, not of the texture.

[image]

The receiving objects  (in your case the ground plane) have to be set to **receive transparent**.

[image]

Comment: did this setting move in the newer versions?